# Dataset created with Az PowerShell not showing in Data Factory Studio

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-powershell

I've created a new dataset in my data factory using the command

```
Set-AzDataFactoryV2Dataset
```

This command ran successfully and now when I run the command

```
Get-AzDataFactoryV2Dataset
```

I can see my new dataset as well as the other datasets I had previously created in the Data Factory Studio. However, the new dataset does not show up in Azure Data Factory Studio or the Git repo for the factory.

I've refreshed the Data Factory Studio page many times and also published the factory using the "publish" button in Data Factory Studio.

If I try to create the same dataset from Az Powershell again, it promps to ask me if I want to override the existing dataset. So the dataset seems to exist in the Powershell environment but not in the studio environment.

Is there a sort of Push command that I have to run from Azure Powershell? I can't find anything about it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you look into the JSON of the datasets to see if your dataset is there? Or maybe just not showing up in UX ?

Comment: The dataset is not there in the dataset folder of the repo. The datasets I had created using the studio are there.

Comment: I ended up creating a new data factory in the portal and reinstalling integration runtime on my machine to create a linked service with the sql server on my machine. Now it works. I don't know what the problem with the other data factory was, I had done the exact same thing, apart from the fact that I had created a git repo for it and I haven't done so for the new one yet.

Comment: When you create a dataset using PowerShell, it's not automatically committed to the Git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Create Azure DataFactory via PowerShell Follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-powershell#create-datasets) created DataFactory/Datasets in Azure Data Factory Studio .

Created via PowerShell with the same azure DataFactory/dataset with the same names I got the below error.
[image]

Suppose we create datasets with the same names in the existing Powershell environment or azure data factory studio environment. It gets a prompt error.

[image]

Using the new name in azure DataFactory/dataset was successfully created and reflected in Azure Data Factory Studio.

[image]

Azure Data Factory Studio and created dataset

[image]

Reflected datasets in PowerShell

[image]

Now I got both datasets reflected in both Azure DataFactory Studio datasets and showing the same details in PowerShell.